# How do I fix SessionNotCreatedException on ios-driver for Selenium?

Tags: java, ios, macos, selenium, automated-tests

I tried to run a selenium test using ios-driver (http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/setup.html) on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with the integrated Simulator that ships with XCode.

I did the following:

1.) Start up ios-server:

```
$ java -jar ios-server-0.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar -port 5555 -simulators
16:39:412 INFO ApplicationStore.<init>  App archive folder:/Users/valmar/Downloads/applications
16:40:492 WARNING AppleLanguage.create  no isn't recognized.Please file a bug on github.You won't be able to start the app in that language.
16:40:970 WARNING AppleLanguage.create  zh_CN isn't recognized.Please file a bug on github.You won't be able to start the app in that language.
16:40:991 WARNING AppleLanguage.create  zh_TW isn't recognized.Please file a bug on github.You won't be able to start the app in that language.
16:41:058 INFO IOSServer.init  
Beta features enabled ( enabled by -beta flag ): false
Simulator enabled ( enabled by -simulators flag): true
Inspector: http://0.0.0.0:5555/inspector/
tests can access the server at http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub
server status: http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/status
Connected devices: http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/devices/all
Applications: http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/applications/all
Capabilities: http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/capabilities/all
Monitoring '/Users/valmar/Downloads/applications' for new applications
Archived apps /Users/valmar/Downloads/applications
using xcode install : /Applications/Xcode.app
using IOS version 7.0
ios >= 6.0. Safari and hybrid apps are supported.

Applications :
--------------- 
    CFBundleName=Safari,CFBundleVersion=9537.53

2014-02-13 16:16:41.059:INFO::jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
2014-02-13 16:16:41.186:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:5555
```

2.) Fire up simulator:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app &
```

3.) Create my selenium test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = IOSCapabilities.iphone();
    caps.setCapability(IOSCapabilities.SIMULATOR, true);
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"), caps);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

4.) ... and all I get is this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: {simulator=true, timeHack=false, variation=Regular, locale=en_GB, CFBundleName=Safari, device=iphone, language=en}not available. Available are [Simulator]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 625 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'tacbook13.local', ip: '172.20.10.4', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at MobSelTest.main(MobSelTest.java:21)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: {simulator=true, timeHack=false, variation=Regular, locale=en_GB, CFBundleName=Safari, device=iphone, language=en}not available. Available are [Simulator]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'tacbook13.local', ip: '172.20.10.4', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.uiautomation.ios.server.command.uiautomation.NewSessionNHandler.handle(NewSessionNHandler.java:54)
    at org.uiautomation.ios.server.command.BaseCommandHandler.handleAndRunDecorators(BaseCommandHandler.java:86)
    at org.uiautomation.ios.server.servlet.IOSServlet.getResponse(IOSServlet.java:144)
    at org.uiautomation.ios.server.servlet.IOSServlet.process(IOSServlet.java:85)
    at org.uiautomation.ios.server.servlet.IOSServlet.doPost(IOSServlet.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

In server console I see this message:

```
34:33:904 WARNING IOSServlet.getResponse  359ms.    POST     /session
```

What's wrong? I have no idea how to debug this.

---

**Update:** Here are some status messages from ios-server:

```
From http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/status

{
  "class": "org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response",
  "hCode": 57594336,
  "sessionId": null,
  "state": null,
  "status": 0,
  "value": {
    "build": {
      "revision": "120cf4311807e2e137e519f4c4877cf6340d0cbc",
      "time": "20130927-1435",
      "version": "0.6.5"
    },
    "ios": {"simulatorVersion": "7.0"},
    "java": {"version": "1.7.0_51"},
    "os": {
      "arch": "x86_64",
      "name": "Mac OS X",
      "version": "10.9.1"
    },
    "state": "success",
    "supportedApps": [{
      "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion": "English",
      "CFBundleDisplayName": "Safari",
      "CFBundleExecutable": "MobileSafari",
      "CFBundleIcons": {"CFBundlePrimaryIcon": {
        "CFBundleIconFiles": [
          "icon-spotlight~ipad.png",
          "icon-table~ipad.png",
          "icon-about~ipad.png",
          "icon-table~ipad.png",
          "icon-spotlight@2x.png",
          "icon-table@2x.png",
          "icon~ipad.png",
          "icon-about@2x.png",
          "icon@2x~iphone.png",
          "icon@2x~ipad.png"
        ],
        "UIPrenderedIcon": true
      }},
      "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.apple.mobilesafari",
      "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion": "6.0",
      "CFBundlePackageType": "APPL",
      "CFBundleShortVersionString": "7.0",
      "CFBundleSignature": "????",
      "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms": ["iPhoneSimulator"],
      "CFBundleURLTypes~ipad": [
        {
          "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
            "http",
            "https"
          ]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
          "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
        }
      ],
      "CFBundleURLTypes~iphone": [
        {
          "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
            "http",
            "https"
          ]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Radar URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
            "rdar",
            "radar"
          ]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
          "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
        }
      ],
      "CFBundleURLTypes~ipod": [
        {
          "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
            "http",
            "https"
          ]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Radar URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
            "rdar",
            "radar"
          ]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
        },
        {
          "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
          "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
          "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
        }
      ],
      "CFBundleVersion": "9537.53",
      "DTPlatformName": "iphonesimulator",
      "DTSDKName": "iphonesimulator7.0",
      "LSRequiresIPhoneOS": true,
      "MallocBehavior": {"NanoAllocator": false},
      "SBMatchingApplicationGenres": [
        "Productivity",
        "Utilities"
      ],
      "SBUsesNetwork": 3,
      "SafariProductVersion": "7.0",
      "UIApplicationDisableLegacyAutorotationKey": true,
      "UIBackgroundModes": [
        "audio",
        "continuousFallback"
      ],
      "UIBackgroundStyle": "UIBackgroundStyleDarkBlur",
      "UIDeviceFamily": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "UIHasPrefs": true,
      "UIStatusBarTintParameters": {"UINavigationBar": {"Style": "UIBarStyleDefault"}},
      "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations": [
        "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",
        "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft",
        "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"
      ],
      "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad": [
        "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",
        "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft",
        "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight",
        "UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown"
      ],
      "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance": true,
      "applicationPath": "/Users/valmar/.ios-driver/safariCopies/safari-7.0.app",
      "device": "iphone",
      "deviceAlt": [
        "iphone",
        "ipod",
        "ipad"
      ],
      "device_Alt": [
        "iphone",
        "ipad"
      ],
      "resources": {"CFBundleIconFile": "/wd/hub/resources/hash=2134756163"},
      "sdkVersion": "7.0",
      "sdkVersion_Alt": [
        "5.0",
        "5.1",
        "6.0",
        "6.1"
      ],
      "simulator": true,
      "supportedLanguages": [
        "hr",
        "ro",
        "ca",
        "vi",
        "tr",
        "fr",
        "unknown",
        "hu",
        "unknown",
        "th",
        "id",
        "pt-PT",
        "en-GB",
        "fi",
        "unknown",
        "sv",
        "it",
        "sk",
        "ja",
        "uk",
        "es",
        "da",
        "ms",
        "ko",
        "ar",
        "he",
        "en",
        "nl",
        "cs",
        "el",
        "pl",
        "pt",
        "ru",
        "de"
      ],
      "timeHack": false,
      "variation": "Regular"
    }]
  }
}
```

---

```
From http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/devices/all

- none
```

---

```
From http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/applications/all

Simulator Apps

com.apple.mobilesafari

{
  "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion": "English",
  "CFBundleDisplayName": "Safari",
  "CFBundleExecutable": "MobileSafari",
  "CFBundleIcons": {"CFBundlePrimaryIcon": {
    "CFBundleIconFiles": [
      "icon-spotlight~ipad.png",
      "icon-table~ipad.png",
      "icon-about~ipad.png",
      "icon-table~ipad.png",
      "icon-spotlight@2x.png",
      "icon-table@2x.png",
      "icon~ipad.png",
      "icon-about@2x.png",
      "icon@2x~iphone.png",
      "icon@2x~ipad.png"
    ],
    "UIPrenderedIcon": true
  }},
  "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.apple.mobilesafari",
  "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion": "6.0",
  "CFBundlePackageType": "APPL",
  "CFBundleShortVersionString": "7.0",
  "CFBundleSignature": "????",
  "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms": ["iPhoneSimulator"],
  "CFBundleURLTypes~ipad": [
    {
      "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
        "http",
        "https"
      ]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
      "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
    }
  ],
  "CFBundleURLTypes~iphone": [
    {
      "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
        "http",
        "https"
      ]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Radar URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
        "rdar",
        "radar"
      ]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
      "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
    }
  ],
  "CFBundleURLTypes~ipod": [
    {
      "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
        "http",
        "https"
      ]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Radar URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": [
        "rdar",
        "radar"
      ]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
    },
    {
      "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
      "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
      "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
    }
  ],
  "CFBundleVersion": "9537.53",
  "DTPlatformName": "iphonesimulator",
  "DTSDKName": "iphonesimulator7.0",
  "LSRequiresIPhoneOS": true,
  "MallocBehavior": {"NanoAllocator": false},
  "SBMatchingApplicationGenres": [
    "Productivity",
    "Utilities"
  ],
  "SBUsesNetwork": 3,
  "SafariProductVersion": "7.0",
  "UIApplicationDisableLegacyAutorotationKey": true,
  "UIBackgroundModes": [
    "audio",
    "continuousFallback"
  ],
  "UIBackgroundStyle": "UIBackgroundStyleDarkBlur",
  "UIDeviceFamily": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "UIHasPrefs": true,
  "UIStatusBarTintParameters": {"UINavigationBar": {"Style": "UIBarStyleDefault"}},
  "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations": [
    "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",
    "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft",
    "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"
  ],
  "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad": [
    "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",
    "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft",
    "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight",
    "UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown"
  ],
  "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance": true
}
```

---

```
From: http://0.0.0.0:5555/wd/hub/capabilities/all

com.apple.mobilesafari on iphone(Simulator)

{
    "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion": "English",
    "CFBundleDisplayName": "Safari",
    "CFBundleExecutable": "MobileSafari",
    "CFBundleIcons": {
        "CFBundlePrimaryIcon": {
            "CFBundleIconFiles": ["icon-spotlight~ipad.png", "icon-table~ipad.png", "icon-about~ipad.png", "icon-table~ipad.png", "icon-spotlight@2x.png", "icon-table@2x.png", "icon~ipad.png", "icon-about@2x.png", "icon@2x~iphone.png", "icon@2x~ipad.png"],
            "UIPrenderedIcon": true
        }
    },
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.apple.mobilesafari",
    "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion": "6.0",
    "CFBundlePackageType": "APPL",
    "CFBundleShortVersionString": "7.0",
    "CFBundleSignature": "????",
    "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms": ["iPhoneSimulator"],
    "CFBundleURLTypes~ipad": [{
        "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["http", "https"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
        "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
    }],
    "CFBundleURLTypes~iphone": [{
        "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["http", "https"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Radar URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["rdar", "radar"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
        "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
    }],
    "CFBundleURLTypes~ipod": [{
        "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web App URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["webclip"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web site URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["http", "https"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Radar URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["rdar", "radar"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "FTP URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["ftp"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLName": "Web Search URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["x-web-search"]
    }, {
        "CFBundleURLIsPrivate": true,
        "CFBundleURLName": "MobileSafari Tab URL",
        "CFBundleURLSchemes": ["com-apple-mobilesafari-tab"]
    }],
    "CFBundleVersion": "9537.53",
    "DTPlatformName": "iphonesimulator",
    "DTSDKName": "iphonesimulator7.0",
    "LSRequiresIPhoneOS": true,
    "MallocBehavior": {
        "NanoAllocator": false
    },
    "SBMatchingApplicationGenres": ["Productivity", "Utilities"],
    "SBUsesNetwork": 3,
    "SafariProductVersion": "7.0",
    "UIApplicationDisableLegacyAutorotationKey": true,
    "UIBackgroundModes": ["audio", "continuousFallback"],
    "UIBackgroundStyle": "UIBackgroundStyleDarkBlur",
    "UIDeviceFamily": [1, 2],
    "UIHasPrefs": true,
    "UIStatusBarTintParameters": {
        "UINavigationBar": {
            "Style": "UIBarStyleDefault"
        }
    },
    "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations": ["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait", "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft", "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],
    "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad": ["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait", "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft", "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight", "UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown"],
    "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance": true,
    "applicationPath": "/Users/valmar/.ios-driver/safariCopies/safari-7.0.app",
    "device": "iphone",
    "deviceAlt": ["iphone", "ipod", "ipad"],
    "device_Alt": ["iphone", "ipad"],
    "sdkVersion": "7.0",
    "sdkVersion_Alt": ["5.0", "5.1", "6.0", "6.1"],
    "simulator": true,
    "supportedLanguages": ["hr", "ro", "ca", "vi", "tr", "fr", "unknown", "hu", "unknown", "th", "id", "pt-PT", "en-GB", "fi", "unknown", "sv", "it", "sk", "ja", "uk", "es", "da", "ms", "ko", "ar", "he", "en", "nl", "cs", "el", "pl", "pt", "ru", "de"],
    "timeHack": false,
    "variation": "Regular"
}
```

Comment: The grid server has a admin page on it where you can monitor active sessions: I dont remember the URI.  Also, what does '/wd/hub/status'  show?

Comment: @djangofan I added everything I could get from ios-server regarding logs and statuses to my original post, however, I could not find any information regarding sessions...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is append the port and simulators on the end if you are using t for web app

This was working for me up until a couple of hours ago:
java -jar ios-server-0.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar -port 5555 -simulators

I updated my Xcode to 5.0.2 and not i'm getting a seperate error

Comment: As you can see in my original posting, that's what I did: `java -jar ios-server-0.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar -port 5555 -simulators`

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed, that you use Mavericks - it is a known issue on this OS.
It has been fixed, but at the moment you'll need to clone the repository and build from the latest source.

See: https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver/issues/169

skyzyx has got it going.